# Parameter optional in base class method but required in child class method

Tags: python, mypy, pylint, python-typing

In the example below, I have a function `maybe_multiply`, where the input and output are optional in the base class but not in the child class. Is there a way to structure this code that avoids violating the the `signature-differs` error in pylint and the `signature-incompatible` error in mypy?

```py
from typing import Optional

class Base:
    def __init__(self, factor: int):
        self.factor = factor

    def maybe_multiply(self, x: Optional[int] = None) -> Optional[int]:
        if x is None:
            return x
        return self.factor*x


class Child(Base):

    def maybe_multiply(self, x: int) -> int:
        return super().maybe_multiply(x=x)
```

Comment: You _should_ get that error - `Child` breaks the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), it can't be used in places where `Base` would be fine. `instance: Base = Child()` is valid, but then `instance.maybe_multiply()` would fail.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I realize I should get the error. I was asking how to structure the code in a way that avoids it.

Comment: For the parameters, either: `x` is optional in both; `x` is required in both; or `x` is required in `Base` but optional in `Child`. The return type is already OK.

Comment: how to structure the code depends a lot on your use case. That might be too broad a Qu for SO